# how to Run Function parallelly in windows Application

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker, background-process

In my windows Application I have one function which I have to run every 6sec.
so, i am using `System.windows.forms.Timer` toolbar
-> Set its Interval 6000ms
and call that Function on that timer tick Event

```
     private void tmrConnectionStatus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             CheckClientConnectinStatus();
         }
```

its Work Perfectly,
but When I am Calling Other Windows Application by Below Function .. Its Not Working until or unless I Return From  that Application to the main Application

```
                 clsLogs.LogEvent(3, "==============Call to PNS ==============");
                        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                        startInfo.FileName = strVendorfile; //Vendors exe
                        startInfo.Arguments = "";           //CSV file path

                        clsLogs.LogEvent(1, "SmartTracker to PRINT-N-SPECT:" + System.DateTime.Now);
                        objProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);       
 Lable:
                        Process[] appProc;
                        string strModName, strProcName;
                        strModName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName;
                        strProcName = "PnS";
                        appProc = Process.GetProcessesByName(strProcName);

                        if (appProc.Length > 0)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            goto Lable;
                        }
```

I want to Know Is there any way to use timer or Other method by which Work in Background Continuously, Even if My Focus On Other Application.

Comment: Look into this [All-about-NET-Timers-A-Comparison](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167365/All-about-NET-Timers-A-Comparison) .

Comment: which timer you are using??

Comment: as I mention in my Question I am using **System.windows.forms.Timer**

Answer (score 0):

You can use backgroundworker.It will work in background.

Answer (score 0):

This article provides an excellent comparison and should contain the information you need: [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

```
                                    Windows.Forms  System.Timers         System.Threading 
Timer event runs on what thread?    UI thread      UI or worker thread   Worker thread 
Instances are thread safe?          No             Yes                   No 
Familiar/intuitive object model?    Yes            Yes                   No 
Requires Windows Forms?             Yes            No                    No 
Metronome-quality beat?             No             Yes*                  Yes* 
Timer event supports state object?  No             No                    Yes 
Initial timer event schedulable?    No             No                    Yes 
Class supports inheritance?         Yes            Yes                   No

* Depending on the availability of system resources (for example, worker threads)
```

**Note:** There is also a `System.Windows.Forms.Time`r class. That class is based on operating system timer support, and if you are not pumping messages on the thread, your timer will not occur. This makes the `System.Threading.Timer` more useful in many scenarios.